# how to get a specific data from json/jsonp result?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, jsonp, response

I have a json response from an Weather API. I want to get a particular property's data, here is the response:

```
 {
    "response": {
        "version": "0.1",
        "termsofService": "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
        "features": {
            "forecast": 1
        }
    },
    "forecast": {
        "txt_forecast": {
            "date": "2:00 PM PDT",
            "forecastday": [
                {
                    "period": 0,
                    "icon": "partlycloudy",
                    "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
                    "title": "Tuesday",
                    "fcttext": "Partly cloudy in the morning, then clear. High of 68F. Breezy. Winds from the West at 10 to 25 mph.",
                    "fcttext_metric": "Partly cloudy in the morning, then clear. High of 20C. Windy. Winds from the West at 20 to 35 km/h.",
                    "pop": "0"
                },
                {
                    "period": 1,
                    "icon": "partlycloudy",
                    "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
                    "title": "Tuesday Night",
                    "fcttext": "Mostly cloudy. Fog overnight. Low of 50F. Winds from the WSW at 5 to 15 mph.",
                    "fcttext_metric": "Mostly cloudy. Fog overnight. Low of 10C. Breezy. Winds from the WSW at 10 to 20 km/h.",
                    "pop": "0"
                }......
```

i want to get the **forecast: txt_forecast : fcttext** i want to get "fcttext" from the above response.. I can get the date using the below code.

```
 var date = parsed_json['forecast']['txt_forecast']['date'];
```

please help me how can i get the "fcttext" from the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`txt_forecast.forecastday` is an array.  Each element of the array is an object that contains an instance of `fcttext`.  If you wanted to get the first element, you could do:

```
parsed_json['forecast']['txt_forecast']['forecastday'][0]['fcctext']
```

Comment: What does `parsed_json['forecast']['txt_forecast']['forecastday'][0]` return?

Comment: I misspelled `fcctext`.  I fixed my answer, try again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for(var forcast_arr_index in parsed_json['forecast']['txt_forecast']['forcastday'])
    console.log(parsed_json['forecast']['txt_forecast']['forcastday'][forcast_arr_index]['fcctest']);
```

Be careful about the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
        var forecastday_arr = obj.forecast.txt_forecast.forecastday;
        jQuery(forecastday_arr).each(function(i){
            var forecastday_obj = forecastday_arr[i];
            console.log(forecastday_obj);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to do something like this, seeing as **fcttext** is inside **forecastday** and **forecastday** is an `Array`...

```
$.each(parsed_json.forecast.txt_forecast.forecastday, function(key, object){
     console.log(object.fcttext);
     alert(object.fcttext);
});
```

This will loop through the **forecastday** object and tell you the value of it's **fcttext**.

Used `$,ajax;` because of the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) tag, you can use `Array.forEach` or `for`.

> ### Links
>
> http://api.jquery.com/each      -    `jQuery.each` Documentation
>
> [https://developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)  -     `Array.forEach` Documentation
>
> [https://developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)  -     `for` Documentation